# Excel 2010-Protecting Sheet while allowing rows to carry formatting when tabbed into

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that allows the user to enter information into a row and when they tab to the new row formatting and drop downs populate for the new row, this happens all the way down the sheet. I need this sheet to be protected from format changes. When I protect the sheet the formatting works for my original first row, but when I tab to the second row it does not carry the formatting and drop downs with it. I am a newer Excel user and any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

file:///U:/mlundgren/Desktop/Capture.JPG

The row of cells with boarders is filled in with numbers and text for each column, there is formatting linked to each column and some columns have drop down lists. When the user reaches the Notes and hits tab, the new row is automatically populated with the formatting and drop down lists from the initial row and text and numbers can be keyed in for that row. It continues this way all the way down the sheet. I want to protect the sheet to allow the user to only enter into the fields that are required and not be able to edit anything else. Once I turn on the protection the features in the row work for the initial row but when the user hits tab nothing populates.

Comment: What did you mean by drop down populate next row and how formatting happens? upload your sheets screenshot link here if possible. Can you try xlsm extension to use vba? Otherwise, pnuts is right.

Comment: I have added an image of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your image won't load.

Comment: @Megan use sharing site like tinypic, dropshots or dropbox etc to upload image.

Comment: Here is a new image https://www.dropbox.com/s/ycv6p0z8ggwtawm/Excel%20File.JPG?dl=0